# How to set the CommandParameter to the ListView item itself in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, code-behind, icommand

I'm using a custom ViewCell defined in C# to populate a ListView in Xamarin.Forms. The ViewCell contains an Image, that acts as a button and when clicked, should be able to manipulate the underlying data of the ListView.

Basically I am looking for the code behind equivalent for:

```
<Image.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer                                           
        Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.PlusClickedCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=ChallengesLV}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
</Image.GestureRecognizers>
```

I have tried:

```
plusButton.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer() {
Command = bindingContext.AddProgressToChallengeCommand, 
CommandParameter = new Binding(".")} });
```

But it gives me an NullReference exception when I try to access the object of type Challenge in my viewmodel like so:

```
AddProgressToChallengeCommand = new Command( (sender) => doSomething((Challenge)sender) );
```

When I inspect the sender object in debug mode, it tells me it is an object of type Binding with every property null except path="."

How do I get the Item this Binding refers to?

Comment: I believe you need to use Command<Challenge> to pass a parm of type Challenge - the sender is not the parm

Comment: You are right, I needed to change it. In addition, I needed to add
    myTapGestureRecognizer.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameterProperty, ".");
Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jason:
The Command needs to be initialized like that, to access the parameter:

```
AddProgressToChallengeCommand = new Command<Challenge>( (challenge) => 
doSomething(challenge);
```

And for the recognizer binding, I needed to change it to:

```
var recognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer() {Command = bindingContext.AddProgressToChallengeCommand};
recognizer.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameterProperty, ".");
plusButton.GestureRegognizers.Add(recognizer);
```